# Jasmine mock value in if statement test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have an if-else statement in a function. I want to test both cases. When the instance is initiated, `self.count` is set to `1`. When I run my test, it goes to the false statement. How can I make `self.count = 2` to go into the else statement?

Test:

```
it('verify change', function () {
    spyOn(this.instance, 'change').and.callThrough();
    this.instance.change('messageBoard');
    expect(this.instance.change).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Javascript:

```
self.count = 1;

self.change = function change() {
    if(self.count <= 1) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

I know I can use `this.object.method.and.returnValue()` to make a method return a value, but I don't know how to do it with variables.

Comment: Wouldn’t that just be a regular unit test? Just run your function twice with both values. What have you tried?

Comment: @Xufox I have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

So it seems i do not need to mock the variables. I can just assign it within the test like:

```
it('verify change', function () {
    this.instance.count = 2; // this would nake it go to the else block
    spyOn(this.instance, 'change').and.callThrough();
    this.instance.change('messageBoard');
    expect(this.instance.change).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```